# "Germs" - a C++ assignment, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c++

**Description:**

There is a square petri dish with the lenghth and width both L, and L*L slots in it. Some slots contain germs, some contain antibiotics and some are clean. Every germ will reproduce individually, and one germ will reproduce in all four neighbourhoods one day, except for ones with antibiotics. Find out how many days it will take to make the whole dish filled?

**Input Format:**

Line 1: One integer
Line 2 - L+1 : L integer each line, values 0, 1, 2, represeting no germs, with germs, with antibiotics, respectively.

**Ouput Format:**

Integer m: How many days will germs fill in every slot of the petri dish(except for those with antibiotics)

**Sample Input**

```
3
2 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 0
```

**Sample Output**

```
2
```

**Data Range**

1<=L<=100, given data can eventually fill the dish.

My code is here

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int L,i,j=0;
bool flag=false;
int m=0;
int cell[100][100]={3};

int main()
{
    cin>>L;
    for (i=1;i<=L;i++)
      for (j=1;j<=L;j++)
        cin>>cell[i][j];

    while (!flag){
        flag=true;
            for (i=1;i<=L;i++)
              for (j=1;j<=L;j++)
              {
                if (cell[i][j]==1){
                   if (cell[i-1][j]==0){
                       cell[i-1][j]=1;
                       flag=false;}
                   if (cell[i+1][j]==0){
                       cell[i+1][j]=1;
                       flag=false;}
                   if (cell[i][j-1]==0){
                       cell[i][j-1]=1;
                       flag=false;}
                   if (cell[i][j+1]==0){
                       cell[i][j+1]=1;
                       flag=false;}
                   }
                if (cell[i][j]==0) flag=false;  
             }
        m=m+1;
        }

    m=m-1;
    cout<<m;
    return 0;
}
```

But the Online Judge says:

```
Judging... PROB=1003 LANG=C++

Wrong Answer (Time: 0ms, Memory: 4796kb)
Accepted (Time: 0ms, Memory: 4832kb)
Wrong Answer (Time: 0ms, Memory: 4852kb)
Wrong Answer (Time: 0ms, Memory: 4868kb)
Wrong Answer (Time: 0ms, Memory: 4944kb)
Wrong Answer (Time: 0ms, Memory: 5024kb)
Wrong Answer (Time: 0ms, Memory: 5100kb)
Wrong Answer (Time: 0ms, Memory: 5188kb)
Wrong Answer (Time: 0ms, Memory: 5180kb)
Wrong Answer (Time: 10ms, Memory: 5192kb)
```

What is wrong with my implementation? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: And you do get the correct answer for the sample? What have you been able to narrow it down to?

Comment: @Bart I got the sample correct. But as you can see from th judging result,only 1 out of 10 test data is correct. :(

Comment: The best things for you to do is come up with some samples and expected answer and then see if your output matches that. And keep in mind that formatting might be very important. It wouldn't be the first time that someone fails a test based on formatting of the output alone. Other than that, @OliCharlesworth is right.

Comment: its also worth pointing out that your code doesnt seem to take into account if the solution is possible at all.  consider the input: 3 1 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0.

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting the array in front of you.
For example with this input:

```
2
1 0
0 0
```

your program will answer `1` instead of `2`.
The reason is, that after you process the top left corner, your array looks like this:

```
1 1
1 0
```

Which is correct, but in the same cycle of the top level `while`
you also simulate the bottom left corner, which spreads to the bottom right and finishes the simulation immediately.

One sollution to this is to use two arrays, reading from one, writing to the other, and swap them at the end of each cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying the array that you're reading from. For each step, you need to place the new format into a new array (actually, only 2 are need, as you can copy back and forth between them).

The problem arrises when a germ at say 1,1 grows into 1,2, which is then checked and grows into cell 1,3 and so on.

You are also starting your search from 1,1 (you may want to either start at 0,0 and extend your array to 1002 by 1002 in size.

You also need to check if the cells you are growing to are actually inside the dish (currently, your germs can grow outside the dish (from inside), thus giving an incorrect result).